# Anyway to change a php variable on the fly by external means?

Tags: php, workflow

Sometimes, I have to test for different layout based on the contents of a variable.

I would prefer to change the content of this variable on the fly, ideally through an external mean like the console or something so I don't have to inject test scripts to my base code.
Then I could do something like, `set myVar layout=2` after I'd verified that layout 1 is fine and refresh the page.

Is this possible? How can I do this?

Comment: what about using $_GET to parse the var? `/index.php?layout=2` .. `$layout=$_GET['layout']`

Comment: that would work. was wondering if there's a way to change it without having to modify our base code.

Comment: sounds dangerous, if there was a magic "inject variable" code - who would be likely to use it?

Comment: ya..that'll only be for development purposes.

Comment: sounds like editing the code base for testing purposes to me.

Answer (score 0):

You want the power of running your script with a debugger like Xdebug.  With it you can use its functionality to alter variables during the running of your script.

After a very quick google there's plenty of tutorials on Xdebug, for example, see this link for a brief explanation on what xdebug is and what it can do:  http://jtreminio.com/2012/07/xdebug-and-you-why-you-should-be-using-a-real-debugger/

Comment: hm...could xdebug change the variable like the example I gave above?